# when space included datalist only showing first part

Tags: jquery, datalist

I have a text box with combo as shown below. I am using `datalist` to achieve this:

```js
$(function(){
  Customercategory();
})



 function Customercategory() { 
    $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").empty();
        
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value=General id=1></option>');
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value=My Category id=1></option>');
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value=New Category id=1></option>');
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value=Last Category id=1></option>');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Customercategory" list="ddlCustomercategoryIdList" id="ddlCustomercategoryId" class="form-control" placeholder="--Select Category--"/>
 
<datalist id="ddlCustomercategoryIdList">
</datalist>
```

As you can see when space is given in the value then only first part is displaying in the drop down.

only displaying `new` instead of `new category`

How do I correct this?

I am using dynamic append function for this.

```
   // Populating Customercategory Dropdwonlist
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CustomerMaster.aspx/Getcustomercategory",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            Customercategory(data.d);
        },
        error: function (msg) { }
    });

    function Customercategory(data) {
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").empty();
        for (var i in data) {
            $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value=' + data[i].customercategory + ' id=' + data[i].companyid + '></option>');
        }

    }
```

Comment: $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value="' + data[i].customercategory + '" id="' + data[i].companyid + '"></option>');

Comment: your value and and id should be like this value="Last Category" id="1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing double quotes in the `value` attribute. Since your `append()` function uses single quote to surround the entire HTML, you need to use double quotes for the attributes. You are also missing double quotes for `id`. Furthermore, your `id` value is same and it is a bad practice.

```js
$(function(){
  Customercategory();
})

 function Customercategory() { 
    $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").empty();
        
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value="General" id="1"></option>');
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value="My Category" id="1"></option>');
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value="New Category" id="1"></option>');
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value="Last Category" id="1"></option>');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Customercategory" list="ddlCustomercategoryIdList" id="ddlCustomercategoryId" class="form-control" placeholder="--Select Category--"/>
 
<datalist id="ddlCustomercategoryIdList">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use quotes (`""`) outside the value, it must be used when your value contains white spaces.

Like:

```
value="New Category"
```

```js
$(function(){
  Customercategory();
})



 function Customercategory() { 
    $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").empty();
        
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value="General" id=1></option>');
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value="My Category" id=1></option>');
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value="New Category" id=1></option>');
        $("#ddlCustomercategoryIdList").append('<option class="CustomercategoryComboName" value="Last Category" id=1></option>');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Customercategory" list="ddlCustomercategoryIdList" id="ddlCustomercategoryId" class="form-control" placeholder="--Select Category--"/>
 
<datalist id="ddlCustomercategoryIdList">
</datalist>
```